# TypeError: dropzone__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ is not a constructor

Tags: angular, dropzone, ngxs

All the dropzones that I'm using in my project stoped working from nothing.
I tried to go to in the past few weeks commits and check if was something new in the project, but seems like Angular just dont reconize the component.

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

[ERROR in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmAVp.png)

Comment: Check how you have imported. Refer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435253/webpack-imported-module-is-not-a-constructor

Answer (score 4):

Solved. Just uninstall the following two packages:

```
npm uninstall ngx-dropzone-wrapper
npm uninstall dropzone*
```

And then install these packages in the newest version:

```
npm i dropzone
npm i ngx-dropzone-wrapper
```

Answer (score 2):

on angular 13 what worked for me was, after uninstall

```
npm i dropzone@5
npm i ngx-dropzone-wrapper@10
```

Comment: This is the same as the original answer, only you explicitly specify the versions. That shouldn't be necessary, however.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer when using the ngx-dropzone-wrapper module in angular as per this issue. Hopefully there is a fix for this soon
https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-dropzone-wrapper/issues/151