# TypeError: _query__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.Query is not a constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I created a class named Query in query.ts

```
export class Query { 
   constructor(params?) {...}
}
```

then i created in the same folder query.spec.ts

```
import { Query } from './query';

fdescribe('Query Model', () => {
    let query: Query;

    beforeEach(() => {
        query = new Query({});
    });

    it('should be created Query Model', () => {
        expect(query).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

but i keep getting this error

```
TypeError: _query__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.Query is not a constructor
```

iam working with Angular 12 and karma-jasmine
any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be how you're importing it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60893655/7365461

Comment: no since i am not using `export default class` then the import should be in {}