# How to get file in request body in nextjs 13.2 route handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I was trying to send a post request to my api with formdata. However trying to access the request file in the route handler causes the error below:

```
export async function POST(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    const data = req.files.file
    // const data = req.body
    console.log(data)
}
```

The function call api:

```
    const handleOnSubmit = () => {
        console.log('file', file)
        if (isLoading) return
        setIsLoading(true)
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file)
        axios.post('/api/text', formData)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)

            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple config export and `formidable`:

```js
import formidable from "formidable";

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false, // enable form data 
  },
};

const formidableParse = async (req) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    new formidable.IncomingForm().parse(req, (err, fields, files) =>
      err ? reject(err) : resolve([fields, files])
    )
  );

export async function POST(req, res) {
  const [fields, files] = await formidableParse(req);
  console.log(files)
}
```

**Edit**

Sometimes, you will have to update `formidable` to latest `v3` version.

You also must not forget to add the `Content-Type` header:

```js
axios.post('/api/text', formData, {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
  },
});
```

Comment: when I use formidable, it has an error: - Error: Cannot find module 'xxxx\xxxx\plugins\octetstream.js'

Comment: What is your formidable version?

Comment: "formidable": "^2.1.1",

Comment: Can you try with version 3: `npm i formidable@3.2.5`

Comment: it has a new error for formidable@3.2.5 error - TypeError: .formidable__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.IncomingForm is not a constructor

Comment: Can this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435253/webpack-imported-module-is-not-a-constructor

Comment: How do you import `formidable` in your `POST` handler?

Comment: yes, it fixed the issue, thx. But I also get the another error in IncomingForm. error - TypeError: req.on is not a function. Now I am trying to fix it.

Comment: but I still can't read the file with the error

Comment: Can you give more context of the err?

Comment: error - TypeError: req.on is not a function
    at IncomingForm.parse (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/formidable/src/Formidable.js:182:13)
The error in here
```
    new formidable.IncomingForm().parse(req, (err, fields, files) =>
      err ? reject(err) : resolve([fields, files])
    )
```

Comment: did you add `multipart/form-data` to your `axios.post`?

Comment: yes, I added multipart/form-data in axios.post headers. But it has a same error

Comment: Did you fixed your error?

Comment: not yet fix the error

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

Correct import

```
import { IncomingForm, File } from 'formidable';<code>
```

Bad import

```
import formidable from 'formidable';
```

parse function

```
const parseFiles = async(req: NextApiRequest): Promise<string> => {

return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

    const form = new IncomingForm() ;
    form.parse( req, async( err, fields, files ) => {
        console.log({file: files.file});

        if ( err ) {
            return reject(err);
        }
//The files.file argument is an array
// Example use
        const filePath = await saveFile( files.file[0] as File )
        resolve(filePath);
    })

}) }
```

Versions
formidable: 3.2.5
next: 13.4.6

Answer (score 0):

const formData = await request.formData()